# sklearn DictVectorizer(sparse=False) with a different default value, Impute a constant

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm building a pipeline that starts with a `DictVectorizer` that produces a sparse matrix. Specifying `sparse=True` changes the output from a scipy sparse matrix to a numpy dense matrix which is good, but the next stages in the pipeline complain about `NaN` values, which our obvious outcome of using the `DictVectorizer` in my case. I'd like the pipeline to consider missing dictionary values not as not available but as zero.

`Imputer` doesn't help me as far as I can see, because I want to "impute" with a constant value and not a statistical value dependant of other values of the column.

Following is the code I've been using:

```
vectorize = skl.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer(sparse=False)
variance = skl.feature_selection.VarianceThreshold()
knn = skl.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(4, weights='distance', p=1)

pipe = skl.pipeline.Pipeline([('vectorize', vectorize),
                            # here be dragons ('fillna', ),
                            ('variance', variance),
                            ('knn', knn)])
pipe.fit(dict_data, labels)
```

And some mocked dictionaries:

```
dict_data = [{'city': 'Dubai', 'temperature': 33., 'assume_zero_when_missing': 7},
             {'city': 'London', 'temperature': 12.},
             {'city': 'San Fransisco', 'temperature': 18.}]
```

Notiec that in this example, `assume_zero_when_missing` is missing from most dictionaries, which will lead later estimators to complain about `NaN` values:

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

While the result I'm hoping for is that `NaN` values will be replaced with `0`.

Comment: Do you have a sample data to demonstrate the workflow?

Comment: @NickilMaveli Yes, I edited to add examples data and code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fill the `NaNs` with 0's after converting your `list` of `dictionaries` to a pandas `dataframe` using [`DF.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) as shown:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_data)
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

---

Inorder to use it as steps inside the pipeline estimator, you could write a custom class implementing the `fit` and `transform` methods yourself as shown:

```
class FillingNans(object):
    '''
    Custom function for assembling into the pipeline object 
    '''
    def transform(self, X):
        nans_replaced = X.fillna(0)
        return nans_replaced

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
```

Then, you could modify the manual feature selection steps in pipeline as shown:

```
pipe = skl.pipeline.Pipeline([('vectorize', vectorize),
                             ('fill_nans', FillingNans()),
                             ('variance', variance),
                             ('knn', knn)])
```

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with `fillna`. How do I do that as part of a `Pipeline`?